# multithreading (unable to accessing global variables like ann)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying multithreaded annotation, but complaining with accessing ann
    from `run()`. Do you have any idea?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,parse");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation ann = new Annotation("your sentence here");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
          pipeline.annotate(ann);  
          Tree tree = ann.get(SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(TreeAnnotation.class);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a java question, if it is not and it's specifically a question about stanford-nlp, I might be wrong.

It would help if you posted the exact error you are getting with your code. I guess it is about [accessing a local variable from an anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class/4732617#4732617).

Due to how closure and scoping work in java such variables have to be (effectively depending on java version) final.
Does changing the line to

```
final Annotation ann = new Annotation("your sentence here");
```

help?